# How to specify the framerate with Live555 RTSPServer?

Tags: h.264, live555

I'm trying to put a raw H264 stream into RTSP with Live555 but I ran into a framerate problem.

I've learned that raw H264 streams do not have timestamps.

I'm using Live555's `H264VideoFileServerMediaSubsession`.

The problem is that my raw H264 stream is created with 20fps, but when a client (ffplay) plays the RTSP stream (with the h264 encapsulated), it defaults to 25fps.

Shall I set (force) the framerate in Live555's subsession, or should the raw H264 stream already contain it?

Comment: SPS may contain fps, see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/31342853/3102264

Comment: May contain, yes, but in my case the HW encoder does not fill that info into SPS. Hence, Im looking for a way to do it with Live555. I want to assign some wallclock style timing.

Comment: @mpromonet: do you know by any chance, how shall I set the framerate/fps/timestamps with live555? The encoder's fps capability can change also on the fly, from 20->10, and back. So initialize the framerate to some constant is not good here unfortunately.

Comment: When the fps change, the SPS change too.

Comment: But SPS is created by the encoder in H264 and not by Live555, right?

Comment: It depends on your code, however SPS & PPS are NALU frame generated by the encoder, live555 probably just forward them.  If your code doesnot forward them, this may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: My encoder is actually not "mine", and it's a black box (closed-source) and does not seem producing FPS info into SPS. So Live555 has nothing to forward, and since it defaults to 25fps, all the players are trying to play @25fps, which cause losing the buffer.

Comment: You may compute frame rate at your encoder output and modify the SPS adding FPS information.

Comment: Actually, I have the FPS information from the encoder (via another method), but I could not yet figured out if that's fine if I just drop it into the current SPS. Isn't any checksum calculation done for the SPS?